Our site got listed in large spammy-looking directories. Should we disavow links from these websites?
Recently, we noticed that our site was submitted to large site directories.
There are 20-25 sites like this with almost the same design and 99% structure.
SEO system defines SOME links from such sites as TOXIC. We never submitted our domain to such sites. We have an opinion that backlinks from such typical, same-design sites might harm our site authority / SEO.
Shall we add such "typical" domains to the disavow list?
Thank you!

Related: Is it still needed to disavow in 2023?

Has Google taken manual action against your site in the form of a penalty? See Google's disavow documentation for details on when to disavow.

According to Google's official documentation on Disavowing links:

In most cases, Google can assess which links to trust without additional guidance, so most sites will not need to use this tool.
You should disavow backlinks only if:

You have a considerable number of spammy, artificial, or low-quality links pointing to your site,
AND
The links have caused a manual action, or likely will cause a manual action, on your site.

Google works very hard to make sure that actions on third-party sites do not negatively affect a website. In some circumstances, incoming links can affect Google’s opinion of a page or site. For example, you or an SEO that you’ve hired may have built bad links to your site via paid links or other link schemes that violate our spam policies. First and foremost, we recommend that you remove as many spammy or low-quality links from the web as possible.

Getting linked by low-quality websites or spammy directories happens to all successful websites, and as long as you haven't actively worked or paid for this to happen, you shouldn't have to disavow these links. As Google says, the only use case for disavowing links is if you get a manual penalty for spammy links.
To find out if your site has incurred a manual action from Google, go to the Manual Actions page under "Security & Manual Actions" in Google Search Console. If it says "No issues detected", you're clear, and you don't need to waste your time disavowing any links.
Furthermore, it is worth noting that Google is considering removing its Disavow Link tool at some point. Google representative John Mueller is quoted in this article saying:

We've touched on this over the years... If you have a manual action for link-spam, or if you're certain you'll get one when someone looks, then disavowing can make sense. Most spammy / paid / placed / swapped links are just ignored nowadays. It's rare you'd need it.
In particular, the disavow links tool is not something you'd ever need on a regular basis. I'd consider it a big red flag if any SEO tool reported on "toxic links" and suggested you need to clean it up regularly - that's been wrong for many years now. Don't fall for it," he added.

It is also worth noting that Bing has already removed its own disavow links tool in October 2023.
Finally, I'd like to refer you to UK SEO expert Mark Williams-Cook's response to the question "If an SEO is struggling for time what should they stop doing right now so they can spend more time doing what you suggest in 2024?", from David Bain's "SEO in 2024" interview series:

If an SEO is struggling for time what should they stop doing right now so they can spend more time doing what you suggest in 2024?
Stop analysing, auditing, and disavowing toxic or spammy links. In conversations with the SEOs I speak to regularly, that's just taken as read. However, when I share that point of view in other places, I have quite a number of people telling me that I'm wrong and it's really important to look for spammy links.
You will see AI-collaborated articles on LinkedIn that say things like, ‘toxic links can harm your website and your brand’ and, ‘you need to be looking at spam scores and toxic link scores’. Google has very flatly said (and I don't think there's a reason for them to carefully word this) that they discount rather than penalise those kinds of links.
That makes perfect sense to me because, if they put a negative value on what they class as bad links, there would be a whole economy for doing that to your competitors. We've also just seen Bing depreciate their link disavow tool because they're so confident that they can identify them.
In my book, there are a lot of other things you could do that would provide value. I'd rather have another good link than get rid of 10 of what someone says are bad links.

Hope this helps!

I think its a good idea to add these types of domains to my disavow list. These directories have similar designs and little original content and some links are flagged as toxic, which could harm my website’s SEO and authority. Backlinks from low-quality or irrelevant sites might look unnatural to search engines and affect my rankings.
Although I know Google’s John Mueller has mentioned that you can ignore these kinds of links, but I would rather be cautious and disavow them while focusing on building high-quality backlinks instead.
